# MySQL Faster Select Query | C# Faster Load DataTable

Tags: c#, mysql, mariadb, dataadapter

I am using MariaDB. I have a table that I create for every IoT device at the time of the first insertion with a stored procedure. If anyone wonders Why I create a new table for every device is devices publish data every 5 seconds and it is impossible for me to store all of them in a single table.

So, my table structure is like below:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mqttpacket_',device_serial_number,'`(
`data_type_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
`data_value` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`inserted_date` DATE DEFAULT NULL, 
`inserted_time` TIME DEFAULT NULL, 
FOREIGN KEY(data_type_id) REFERENCES datatypes(id), 
INDEX `index_mqttpacket`(`data_type_id`,`inserted_date`)) ENGINE = INNODB;
```

I have a very long `SELECT` query like below to fetch the data between selected `type`, `date`, and `time`.

```
SELECT  mqttpacket_123.data_value, datatypes.data_name, datatypes.value_mult,
        CONCAT(mqttpacket_123.inserted_date, ' ',
               mqttpacket_123.inserted_time) AS 'inserted_date_time'
    FROM  mqttpacket_123
    JOIN  datatypes  ON mqttpacket_123.data_type_id = datatypes.id
    WHERE  mqttpacket_123.data_type_id IN(1,2,3,4,5,6)
      AND  CASE WHEN mqttpacket_123.inserted_date = '2021-11-08'
                    THEN mqttpacket_123.inserted_time > '12:25:00'
                WHEN mqttpacket_123.inserted_date = '2021-11-15'
                    THEN mqttpacket_123.inserted_time< '12:25:00'
                ELSE (mqttpacket_123.inserted_date BETWEEN '2021-11-08'
                                                       AND '2021-11-15')
                END;
```

and this returns around 500k records of the sample below:

```
|   data_value  |       data_name       |   value_mult  |   inserted_date_time  |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|       271     |       name_1          |       0.1     |   2021-11-08 12:25:04 |
|       106     |       name_2          |       0.1     |   2021-11-08 12:25:04 |
|       66      |       name_3          |       0.1     |   2021-11-08 12:25:04 |
|       285     |       name_4          |       0.1     |   2021-11-08 12:25:04 |
|       61      |       name_5          |       0.1     |   2021-11-08 12:25:04 |
|       454     |       name_6          |       0.1     |   2021-11-08 12:25:04 |
|       299     |       name_7          |       0.1     |   2021-11-08 12:25:04 |
```

> Affected rows: 0  Found rows: 395,332  Warnings: 0  Duration for 1 query: 0.734 sec. (+ 7.547 sec. network)

I keep only the last 2 weeks' data in my tables and clean up the previous data as I have a backup system.

However, Loading the query result to DataTable also takes ~30sec. which is 4 times slower than MySQL.

Do you have any suggestions to improve this performance?

PS. I call this query from C# by the following statement in a Stored Procedure of `RunQuery` which takes the query and performs it as it is.

```
public DataTable CallStoredProcedureRunQuery(string QueryString)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            try
            {
                using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(_connectionString))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand("SP_RunQuery", conn))
                    {
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@query_string", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = QueryString; 

                        using (MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                        {
                            sda.Fill(dt);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                IoTemplariLogger.tLogger.EXC("Call Stored Procedure for RunQuery failed.", ex);
            }
            return dt;
        }
```

> EDIT: My sensors push a single MQTT packet which contains ~50 different data. There are 12 times `5seconds` in a minute. So, basically, I receive ~600 rows per minute per device.

Data insertion is done in a `Stored Procedure` async. I push the JSON content along with the `device_id` and I iterate on the JSON to parse and `insert into` the table.

PS. The following code is just for clarification. It works fine.

```
/*Dynamic SQL -- IF they are registered to the system but have notable, create it.*/
    SET create_table_query = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mqttpacket_',device_serial_number,'`(`data_type_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, `data_value` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,`inserted_date` DATE DEFAULT NULL, `inserted_time` TIME DEFAULT NULL, FOREIGN KEY(data_type_id) REFERENCES datatypes(id), INDEX `index_mqttpacket`(`data_type_id`,`inserted_date`)) ENGINE = InnoDB;');
    PREPARE stmt FROM create_table_query;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
    
    /*Loop into coming value array. It is like: $.type_1,$.type_2,$.type_3, to iterate in the JSON. We reach each value like $.type_1*/
    WHILE (LOCATE(',', value_array) > 0)
    DO
        SET arr_data_type_name = SUBSTRING_INDEX(value_array,',',1); /*pick first item of value array*/
        SET value_array = SUBSTRING(value_array, LOCATE(',',value_array) + 1); /*remove picked first item from the value_array*/
        
        SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(incoming_data, arr_data_type_name) INTO value_iteration; /*extract value of first item. $.type_1*/
        
        SET arr_data_type_name := SUBSTRING_INDEX(arr_data_type_name, ".", -1); /*Remove the $ and the . to get pure data type name*/
        
        /*Check the data type name exists or not in the table, if not insert and assign it's id to lcl_data_type_id*/
            IF (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM datatypes WHERE datatypes.data_name = arr_data_type_name) > 0 THEN 
                SELECT id INTO lcl_data_type_id FROM datatypes WHERE datatypes.data_name = arr_data_type_name LIMIT 1;
            ELSE
                SELECT devices.device_type_id INTO lcl_device_type FROM devices WHERE devices.id = lcl_device_id LIMIT 1;
                INSERT INTO datatypes (datatypes.data_name,datatypes.description,datatypes.device_type_id,datatypes.value_mult ,datatypes.inserted_time) VALUES(arr_data_type_name,arr_data_type_name,lcl_device_type,0.1,NOW());
                SELECT id INTO lcl_data_type_id FROM datatypes WHERE datatypes.data_name = arr_data_type_name LIMIT 1;
            END IF;
            
            /*To retrieve the table of which device has which datatypes inserted, this is to not to retrieve the datatypes unneccesseraly for the selected device*/
            IF (SELECT COUNT(device_id) FROM devicedatatypes WHERE devicedatatypes.device_id = lcl_device_id AND devicedatatypes.datatype_id = lcl_data_type_id) < 1 THEN
                INSERT INTO devicedatatypes (devicedatatypes.device_id, devicedatatypes.datatype_id) VALUES(lcl_device_id,lcl_data_type_id);
            END IF;
            
            SET lcl_insert_mqtt_query = CONCAT('INSERT INTO mqttpacket_',device_serial_number,'(data_type_id,data_value,inserted_date,inserted_time) VALUES(',lcl_data_type_id,',',value_iteration,',''',data_date,''',''',data_time,''');');
            PREPARE stmt FROM lcl_insert_mqtt_query;
            EXECUTE stmt;
            SET affected_data_row_count = affected_data_row_count + 1;
                        
    END WHILE;
```

[Here](https://pastebin.com/yi03qe0R) and [here](https://pastebin.com/z7fFcc9p) are also extra information that can be found of the server and database regarding the comments.
I have an SSD on the server. There is nothing important else that works other than my `dotnet` application and database.

Comment: I suspect you need an index on Inserted_Date and Inserted_Time columns

Comment: Thanks for your comment @KenTucker but I already have one on the ```inserted_date``` column like 
```INDEX `index_mqttpacket`(`data_type_id`,`inserted_date`)) ENGINE = INNODB;```

Creating an index on the column of time is a very costly action

Comment: Calling BS on this: `"devices publish data every 5 seconds and it is impossible for me to store all of them in a single table."` It's absolutely the exact same amount of I/O either way. Do the indexes right, and queries are the same, too. It's all a matter of defining keys properly.

Comment: Also, that's now how `CASE` expressions work.

Comment: Finally, relying on `SP_RunQuery` looks like it will force you to write code that scary vulnerable to sql injection attacks... to the point it's practically begging to get your app hacked.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your amazing comments @JoelCoehoorn. I totally agree with the vulnerability of my SQL within `SP_RunQuery`. I will change it. 

One thing for the table design; do you really think it will be efficient to read from that table? Daily insertion will be like 1 million per device and if you assume I reach a thousand devices which will make 1 billion rows per day in a single table...

Comment: @TaylanYuksel A day has 86,400 seconds.  If one device sends data every 5 seconds, then in 1 day you would add 17,280 rows for each device. One thousand devices x 17,280 = 17,280,000 rows added per day, nowhere near a billion.  A signicant number, yes.  Keepiing 2 weeks of data = 17,280,000 x 14 days for  241,920,000 rows of capacity neeeded before you roll off the oldest day.  You will never get to 1 billion rows if these numbers and purge cycle details are accurate.

Comment: @RickJames     This looks like 'table per date' storage opportunity to accommodate purge of data tables older than 14 days - drop table older than 14 days. Partitioning might make sense for this app.

Comment: @WilsonHauck Well, first of all, thanks for commenting. Perhaps I couldn't express well that every packet push does not contain a single piece of data. They are usually around 50-60 different data in a packet. Meaning ~50x12=~600 rows per minute per device. Your suggestion about 'table per date' is a very good solution if I wouldn't need to query multiple days in a single query

Comment: Regarding @RickJames comment, I implemented a single table logic and am collecting sample results. If this case doesn't help to solve the speed issue, I will combine his proposition with my `one table per device` logic. That will for sure give me what I need however won't look so pretty in terms of database design.

Comment: Depending on your sensors, `INT` may not be optimal for `data_value`.

Comment: Are you getting a packet of 50 rows to insert?  Or 600?  Either way, turn that into a single `INSERT` statement with multiple rows; this will be efficient if there is a single table.  (It won't be possible with table-per-device.)

Comment: Please provide more on how long you intend to keep the data and what the `SELECTs` look like.  Then we can discuss `PARTITIONing`.

Comment: @RickJames for the `data_value` I decided to store it as `SMALLINT` which is optimal for my sensors. I receive ~50 rows to insert in a single packet as you said. So, 60/5=12 times in a minute which makes ~50x12=600 rows insertion. I will edit the question to clarify it. There's no issue with `Insert` but I will also explain how I do it.

Comment: What is the real world 'change' in the ~ 50 rows per 5 seconds per device?  If the only thing changing is the time of day, why is it necessary to even 'send' the data from the device when there are no changes?  Is this a vehicle 'reporting/tracking' application?  The commercial name of the product?

Comment: @WilsonHauck however I agree with you that's quite unnecessary to send this much data so frequently the company needs to track the **heat pumps**. Every change is important to obtain the machine's behavior.

Comment: Additional information request, please. 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
AND very helpful information, includes -
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: @WilsonHauck I added that information and paste the link into the description. Please be advised that this is just a test server and I run several different databases during the test.

Comment: Thanks for data posted. Additional information request, please. Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? Post on pastebin.com and share the links, please. very helpful information, includes - htop OR top for most active apps, iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: @WilsonHauck I updated the content again as you asked for more details. Kindly give me your feedback

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239318/discussion-between-taylan-yuksel-and-wilson-hauck).

Comment: When would you like to continue in chat?  Please suggest a couple of date/times you have available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- It is usually better to have a `DATETIME` column instead of splitting it into two (`DATE` and `TIME`) columns.  That might simplify the `WHERE` clause.
- Having one table per device is usually a bad idea.  Instead, add a column for the device_id.
- Not having a `PRIMARY KEY` is a bad idea.  Do you ever get two readings in the same second for a specific device?  Probably not.

Rolling those together plus some other likely changes, start by changing the table to

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mqttpacket`(
`device_serial_number` SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`data_type_id` TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`data_value` SMALLINT NOT NULL,
`inserted_at` DATETIME NOT NULL, 
FOREIGN KEY(data_type_id) REFERENCES datatypes(id), 
PRIMARY KEY(device_serial_number, `data_type_id`,`inserted_at`)
) ENGINE = INNODB;
```

That PK will make the query faster.

This may be what you are looking for after the change to `DATETIME`:

```
  AND inserted_at >= '2021-11-08 12:25:00'
  AND inserted_at  < '2021-11-08 12:25:00' + INTERVAL 7 DAY
```

To keep 2 weeks' worth of data, `DROP PARTITION` is an efficient way to do the delete.  I would use `PARTITION BY RANGE(TO_DAYS(inserted_at))` and have 16 partitions, as discussed in http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint

If you are inserting a thousand rows every 5 seconds -- With table-per-device, you would need a thousand threads each doing one insert.  This would be a nightmare for the architecture.  With a single table (as I suggest), and if you can get the 1000 rows together in a process at the same, time, do one multi-row `INSERT` every 5 seconds.  I discuss other [*high speed ingestion*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table).

Comment: I highly appreciate your contribution. I thought so long about having all the data in a single table. But do you think it will be still efficient in the condition of; having a million data per device in a day. So, if we assume that I reach a thousand devices which will make a billion rows insertion per day into a single table. Anyhow I will implement your solution to test. Thanks a lot

Comment: @TaylanYuksel - Do test.  A billion rows per day could be challenging _in either case_.  That's 12K rows per second.  Do you have an SSD disk?  Let me know if either method has trouble inserting that much that fast; I have further tips; some are here:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table

Comment: @TaylanYuksel - I added some stuff about partitioning and ingestion.

Comment: Thankful for your comments. I use an SSD. I also edit the question to show you how I 
`insert` the `data` I will give you feedback regarding your suggestions.

Comment: I read your wonderful articles. I think I will go with a single table and use a partition as you suggested. I have just a question for `partition` do I need to give a name for each partition? Since I don't know the future days' name how would I give it? Is this query correct in this regard? `ALTER TABLE mqttpacket PARTITION BY RANGE(TO_DAYS(inserted_at)) PARTITIONS 16;
`
Also, I don't have an issue with `insert` since I am inserting the data in a single session for every set of data. (like in the description; a stored procedure for each packet)

Comment: One another thing is when I run the `partition` command I get the following error `SQL Error (1217): Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails` when I search the reason for this I come across to **Foreign keys not supported for partitioned InnoDB tables**. In this case, every day before the `drop/add partition` commands should I drop the `Foreign keys` and add them back? This doesn't sound like so convenient solution. I'm sure you have a better solution than what I say... Thanks

Comment: @TaylanYuksel - Normally, the only need for the names of partitions is when doing an `ALTER` (`DROP PARTITION`, `REORGANIZE PARTITION`, etc).  I consider it 'wrong' to use the partition name in `SELECT`.

Comment: @TaylanYuksel - The phrase `PARTITIONS 16` does not apply to `BY RANGE`.  You must have a job that periodically runs to do the `DROP` and `REORGANIZE`.  Alas, MySQL has nothing automated here.

Comment: @TaylanYuksel - Your code is "correct", yes?  The FKs are checking references that are correct, so they waste time.  A partitioned table cannot have FKs; period.  (Nor can it have a `UNIQUE` key that does not include the partition key as part of the uniqueness check.)

Comment: @TaylanYuksel - Without partitioning, deletion of old date will be slooooow.  See this for workarounds:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig

Comment: Well thanks to your comments, I see that I can not use the `partition table` due to foreign keys. I decided to go with the `table per device` logic implementing your table design. Additionally, I will use your **workaround** ways for deleting. All in all, thanks a lot. I accept your answer as an _accepted answer_ since it's a very correct way.

Answer (score 1):

Rate Per Second = RPS

Suggestions to consider for your instance [mysqld] section

```
innodb_io_capacity=500  # from 200 to use more of available SSD IOPS
innodb_log_file_size=256M  # from 48M to reduce log rotation frequency
innodb_log_buffer_size=128M  # from 16M to reduce log rotation avg 25 minutes
innodb_lru_scan_depth=100  # from 1024 to conserve 90% CPU cycles used for function
innodb_buffer_pool_size=10G  # from 128M to reduce innodb_data_reads 85 RPS
innodb_change_buffer_max_size=50  # from 25 percent to expedite pages created 590 RPhr
```

Observation,
`innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT  # from fsync for method typically used on LX systems`

You should find these significantly improve task completion performance.  View profile for free downloadable Utility Scripts to assist with performance tuning.
There are additional opportunities to tune Global Variables.

Comment: I changed the settings as you mentioned. I first time got into this much detail in the database. They all look like very important performance settings. I set those `Global Variables` as you told me. I Upvote your answer but can not accept it as an **accepted answer** as my question is related to database design. But this is a very valuable answer. I appreciate it a lot!

Comment: Could you share with us your perception of speed improvement with the changes applied (after stop/start of instance)?

Comment: Sorry that I don't know how professionally to give feedback in this regard. But I can see that along with the _new database design_ and _your suggestions_ performance improved better. Here I run the `task manager` and crop some information that could be useful to show you. Any further commands to see details please let me know. [PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/izZFDA9Q)

Comment: @TaylanYuksel  Your general feeling of "improved' or 'slower' can be your professional opinion and only you are there to make the assessment.  If you compared the two iostat -xm 5 3 reports from 11/17/2121 and 11/22/2021 you would likely see that changes have enabled higher rates per second of many areas reported.  That tells me performance is better.  View profile for free downloadable Utility Scripts to assist with performance tuning, please.